# Fedora Apache: VirtualHost not picking up DirectoryIndex

Tags: apache, fedora, virtualhost

I am having a problem with virtualhosting on my fedora 18 box.

```
http://127.0.0.1 works correctly and brings up index.html

http://127.0.0.1:9000 also works correctly.

http://localhost works 

http://localhost:9000 does NOT work.  

It just redirects to http://localhost
```

Why is not able to treat localhost and 127.0.0.1 the same way?

Here is the contents of my httpd-vhosts.conf:

Thanks in advance.

```
Listen 9000


  DirectoryIndex index.html welcome.html

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:9000

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName saraslights
  ServerAdmin ratteri@gmail.com
  ServerAlias saraslights
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/opencart"
  ErrorLog "logs/saraslights-errors.log"
  CustomLog "logs/saraslights-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:9000>
  ServerName wordpress
  ServerAdmin ratteri@gmail.com
  ServerAlias wordpress
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
  ErrorLog "logs/wordpress-errors.log"
  CustomLog "logs/wordpress-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Wordpress only works on port 80. It receives the request and redirects you.

Comment: Ignore wordpress for now.  I just want to get virtualhost working.

Comment: Wordpress get the request from :9000 and redirects to :80. The problem is not the virtualhost.